# Gatsby JS - Multiple pages pulling in markdown files with different categorys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am using GatsbyJS to build a personal webpage. I have multiple pages, the two relevant ones are a projects/portfolio page and a blog page.

I have setup gatsby so on the blog page, it pulls in markdown files from a specific folder, and displays them using a template on the blog page. I wanted to display my projects in a similar fashion on the projects/portfolio page.
My folder structure is as follows:

```
-src
 -pages
  -BlogPostOne
  -BlogPostTwo
  projects.js
  blog.js
 -templates
  BlogPostTemplate.js
  ProjectTemplate.js
 -projects
  -project1
  -project2
```

I want the projects page to grab the project markdown files from the projects folder and display them using the project template

The blog page grabs the blog post markdown files from the pages folder and displays them using the blog post template, this works fine.

I basically used the same code as I did to grab the blog post files with different variable names and paths but it doesn't work. Is it possible to even do this with Gatsby? I have searched through their documentation and can't find anything similar to what I am trying to do. Does anyone have any experience doing a similar thing with Gatsby?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is totally possible.

The solution is actually very simple, but requires a little understanding of Gatsby's internals to figure out. See [this snippet on GatsbyCentral](https://www.gatsbycentral.com/add-type-field-for-markdown-sources) if you already know Gatsby a bit.

Otherwise, here's a more verbose explanation.

In your `gatsby-node.js` file, you need to add this code:

```
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, boundActionCreators, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = boundActionCreators;

  if (_.get(node, "internal.type") === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    // Get the parent node
    const parent = getNode(_.get(node, "parent"));

    // Create a field on this node for the "collection" of the parent
    // NOTE: This is necessary so we can filter `allMarkdownRemark` by
    // `collection` otherwise there is no way to filter for only markdown
    // documents of type `post`.
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: "collection",
      value: _.get(parent, "sourceInstanceName")
    });
  }
};
```

Ensure you also have the required `require()` statement for lodash:

```
const _ = require("lodash")
```

Now ensure that you have two plugin sections in `gatsby-config.js` for both blog posts and projects. Ensure that each one has a `name` option, something like:

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
    options: {
      name: "pages",
      path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`
    }
  },
  {
    resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
    options: {
      name: "projects",
      path: `${__dirname}/src/projects`
    }
  },
```

Then you can query on the `allMarkdownRemark` collection and filter for the field `collection`. It will either be `pages` or `projects`.

An example query might look like:

```
query {
  allMarkdownRemark(filter: {fields: {collection: {eq: "pages"}}}) {
  ...
```

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: That's great thank you so much! Marked this as correct for anyone else searching for the same thing. I couldn't find this solution in the documentation anywhere.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful. It's a common source of confusion.

Comment: THANK YOU for this. I have had *such* a hard time getting something like this to work. This is the first answer that I've found that actually solves it. One note: in Gatsby v2 (which came out after this answer) you should update `boundActionCreators` to just `actions`.

Comment: Why do we use lodash here instead of just accessing the properties directly on the node object? (e.g. "node.parent" and "parent.sourceInstanceName"?

Comment: @DavidBerg It's a preference for safe access in case the variable doesn't exist. It's a general habit that I have, which I often apply too much. Sometimes we do want the code to crash if the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You can do it without lodash like this: ```const { parent } = node```.

Comment: @DavidBerg True, but that compiles into `const parent = node.parent` which throws an exception it `node` is undefined, while the lodash version does not. Sometimes crashing is a bonus, sometimes not.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I learned something new. I though deconstruction handled undefined.